# How to convert object to generic class with Type T

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, data-binding, casting

I want to convert an object of type object to a generic class with Type T.

Class:

```cs
public class TestClass<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

Method:

```cs
public void GetValue(object obj)
{
    var genericParameter = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)obj).DataContext.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0];
    var castObject = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)obj).DataContext as TestClass<genericParameter>;

    if (castObject != null)
        castObject.Name = "Test";
}
```

I cannot write `TestClass<genericParameter>`. Only something like `TestClass<int>` or `TestClass<bool>` works.

But I think it is bad to check all the possibilities like:

```cs
public void GetValue(object obj)
{
    var dataContext = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox) obj).DataContext;

    if (dataContext is TestClass<int> castObject1)
        castObject1.Name = "Test";

    if (dataContext is TestClass<bool> castObject2)
        castObject2.Name = "Test";

    if (dataContext is TestClass<double> castObject3)
        castObject3.Name = "Test";

    if (dataContext is TestClass<float> castObject4)
        castObject4.Name = "Test";

    if (dataContext is TestClass<string> castObject5)
        castObject5.Name = "Test";
}
```

Is there any convenient solution to my problem?

Comment: afaik that's not easily possible...you can consider using `dynamic` (which I won't recommend) or give `TestClass<T>` an interface like `interface IHaveAName { string Name {get;set;}}` and cast `obj` to that interface.

Comment: The *actual* question is how to find the type of an `object` variable, not how to convert the `object` to a generic class. It already is one, you're trying to find which one it is. You can't do that without a type check at some point. You can use reflection to retrieve the type of `T` but then you'll have to perform a check to decide what to do with that value.

Comment: **Generics** are called generics because they work for **any** type, not just those you´ve mentioned. In particular they assume your types have anything in common, whch `bool`, `string` and `int` surely don´t have, do they?

Comment: Which stack are you targeting? If you target WPF you don't need such code or even know what `DataContext` contains. It's the job of *data binding* to match types and templates. You can easily specify different templates for different data types.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem X (how to display different UI elements for different bound data items) and assume Y is the solution (type checking in the *View's* code-behind file). When you run into trouble, you ask about Y, not X. The answer to X is [data templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview)

Comment: I'm using a data template for a TextBox. DataContext is the generic class. For validation I use ```ValidatesOnExceptions```. When this exceptions happend the TextBox got red, but the value typed in was still in the TextBox. In addition I want to set a bool the true when ```ValidatesOnExceptions``` caugth something. But I cannot do this. So when the user does some changes to the TextBox the TextBox_TextChanged event is called. To catch that I need a method that excepts an object and EventArgs.  Now I want to check the value entered manually and change the ```TextBoxIsValid``` bool if needed

Comment: Validation with exception is flawed in a very bad way - if you create object with error outside of a binding, you get uncaught exception. Use `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface, slap another one with a `Name` property and you are golden. Go even more MVVM, give objects a property `IsValid`, this will make your life much easier - with proper use of that pattern you will not have this problem

Comment: I already implemented the ```IDataErrorInfo``` interface. When you bind and ```int``` to the TextBox's Text, then you can still type e.g. "bla" in the TextBox and the TextBox turns red. The value is obviously not being converted into and ```int```. But you can still see it in the gui's TextBox. But how do I set the property ```IsValid``` to false? I guess you have the same problem with the ```INotifyDataErrorInfo``` interface? If no please tell me :D

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstandig how generics work in C#. When you write `Foo<T>` in your code, when it compiles, the compiler will *know at compile time* what type `T` really is. Its not something it will figure out at runtime (except if you write `Foo<dynamic>` but that isn't going to solve your problem).

If you understand this basic fact, then its easy to understand that there is no possible way to cast a runtime object with an unknown type at compile time to an open generic type `Foo<T>`; how could you? The compiler needs to know `T` when it compiles! You can only try casting it to closed generic types, that is, types where `T` is *known*. The cast will then succeed or fail at runtime depending on what `T` you actually choose.